# scrapy cralwer cant parse data from mysql database

Tags: python-3.x, flask, scrapy, web-crawler, mysql-python

I build a web cralwer with scrapy and I store data to mysql database (I crawl the source code from a url) and now I would like to do offline edit . So I have create sql queries to export data with python and the I try to crawl from this.

Could you please suggest how to do it. I can't do it with scrapy of actually. I failed to do it with scrapy, if anyone has anys uggestion or similar project and can help me out .

I have tried with scrapy query the database and store data to

```
 from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
import mysql
from mysql.connector import Error
import scrapy
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# this here connect to database and q all url that have been crawled and store it into records.


class database:
    def query():
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='',
                                                 database='',
                                                 user='',
                                                 password='')
            cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
            if connection.is_connected():
                db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
                done = "Connected to MySQL database... MySQL Server version on "
            sql_select_Query = """ SELECT  `job_url`, `job_description` FROM `store_all` WHERE job_url LIKE '%kariera.gr% """
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()
        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            not_done = "Failed to connect {}".format(error)

        return records

    def insert(job_url, metakey, metavalue):
            try:
                connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='',
                                                 database='',
                                                 user='',
                                                 password='')
                cursor = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
                sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO `store`( `url`, `metakey`, `metavalue`, ) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
                insert_tuple = (job_url, metakey, metavalue)
                result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, insert_tuple)
                connection.commit()
                done = "Record inserted successfully into python_users table"
            except mysql.connector.Error as error:
                connection.rollback()
                not_done = "Failed to insert into MySQL table {}".format(error)
            return done

class Crawler(scrapy.Spider,database):
        records =database.query()
        records=records[0]
        response = HtmlResponse(url="Any String", body=records,encoding='utf-8')
        job=response.xpath('//ul[@class="tab_content"]/text()').extract()
        url= records
        metakey= "test"
        metavalue= "test"
        print(database.query())
        print(database.insert(url,metakey,metavalue))
```

Comment: What error message(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

the issue  is solved actually

```
 b = ''.join(body1)

 response = TextResponse(url="Any String", body=b,encoding='utf-8')
```